# How to upgrade Android version of existing AOSP ROM?

Tags: android-source, porting

I have a custom lollipop ROM much similar to this AOSP (rockchip).
https://github.com/rockchip-android
Now I am in need of upgrading its Android version to 6.0 or 7.0.
What is all I have to do for this?
I hope to learn step-by-step process.
Thanks all.